# honda 2002 turns over but will not start (freespins)

Tags: honda, starting, civic, cranks-wont-run

i have a 2002 honda civic that will not start it turns over but will not crank.
it just died when we pulled out of drive and wouldnt start.Just freespins we replaced fuel pump still wont start?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Was there a reason you decided to replace the fuel pump?

Comment: Besides the fuel pump, what else have you checked? Have you had the codes read? First thing which comes to my mind is a cam/crank position sensor, but really, you need to have an idea of what is happening before you throw parts at it. Get us the codes (if there are any) and we can go from there.

Comment: no the codes havent been read .it is at my work and i dont know who knows how to get the codes?i cant drive it anywhere to be checked .He replaced the fuel pump and still doesnt seem to have any fuel under the hood  injectors dry?

Answer (score 2):

just fyi it was my timing belt that broke .we took the bonnet off and while turning over the engine the valves nor anything is moving at all ,but thanks for the imput from all .

Comment: Well, at least you figured out what's going on. Sorry for the issues! We appreciate you coming back and letting us know.